# How to open folder in Finder as root (like right-click on folder does in Linux)?

Tags: macos, finder, big-sur, root

I have always used Linux before and now switched to macOS. I have found a solution for right click button open folder in terminal.

but I also want to have the option to right click and open folder in finder as root. does someone know how to get this ?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't open Finder as root.  If you could, the Terminal command would be 'sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder'. Other apps can be opened as root though the consequences could be bad.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve with Finder opened as root?  There may be better ways to do what you need.

Comment: Yes: it's likely that the method you're used to in Linux for solving {unknown problem} is not the best method for solving the same problem on macOS. Root does NOT have unfettered access to everything. This may be an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 1):

To run Finder as root, you need to login as root.

This is NOT recommended.

You can enable the root user and then login as the root user.  The procedure is covered in this old article by Topher Kessler.

[How to browse another account's files in OS X](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-browse-another-accounts-files-in-os-x/)

But, I repeat, you should NOT do this unless you have a specific need that can't be met by using sudo in Terminal.

It is not something that I would choose to test, but I believe it is still (mostly) accurate.

Answer (score 0):

On the mac, you want to use the Terminal app which opens a Unix window. The terminal app is located in the Applications folder under Utilities. To make it open in one click you can drag the Terminal application to the dock and add it there. Then whenever you click on the Terminal app in the dock it will launch. This will not give you root access. The terminal will open a window to your user's directory. You can navigate to wherever you want. you should be able to direct where to open by checking the preferences under the Terminal menu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. unfortunately that's not what I was searching for. I want to have a option to right click somewhere and then to have a option ''open folder in finder as root'' as how I always did on linux mint. I already have the right mouse button open folder in terminal fixed but now I only need the right click open folder in finder as root option under it

Comment: You're not answering the important question.  What do you need to accomplish that you need to do this?